# Illegal activities in autobiography

Tags: publishing, non-fiction, autobiography

So I want to write a self-help book on how I became Rich from being poor I want to write about my struggles from when I was poor which is including stealing for groceries and other things that I needed. Is it illegal to write about this in the book and if not can I write about what stores or what I had to steal to put in more detail or should I just plainly put that I stole stuff that I needed and that's it so I don't cause any trouble with any companies or with myself. I know it's kind of a dumb question but I wanted my book to be a detailed as possible so I want to make sure that I will not get in trouble for writing about illegal activities.

Comment: Just to clarify - you were the one who (in real life) stole items.

Comment: I think this may be a question for Law.SE rather than Writing.SE. Either way, might I ask when and where these offences took place? If they happened long enough ago that your country's [statute of limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations) has expired, then (AFAIK) you cannot legally be prosecuted for them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Law.SE (asking a legal question).

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this Law SE question: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3381/5348

Comment: This question should be moved to Law. SE, although there has already been a similar question, like Laurel said.

Comment: Look at the statute of limitations for those crimes. Unless you stole a LOT of money, no one will do anything about it. Might not be a bad idea to make token amends for those, if you can track down the victims.

Comment: It's not illegal to **write** about the crimes you've committed. What you're really asking is whether you can be prosecuted for any of the crimes you personally admit to in your book. That's a legal question, not a writing question. There may also be a risk of civil suits - i.e. the victim of the crime sues you for damages.

Comment: This question is a poor fit for SE, including Law.SE.  OP likely wants advice that is personal to his situation.  However, only a lawyer can provide this advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the country you're in, this could amount to a confession. You could end up in legal trouble. It's best to check with a local lawyer.